# Sum up database values by condition

Tags: mysql

I get the total shipping cost with this query

```
SELECT SUM(ot.value/o.currency_value) AS shipping
FROM   orders o
JOIN   orders_total ot ON (ot.orders_id = o.orders_id AND ot.class = 'ot_shipping')
WHERE  o.date_purchased >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
AND    o.date_purchased < '2018-01-02 00:00:00'
AND    o.orders_status != 8
```

The database entries for one order_id look like this

```
INSERT INTO `orders_total` (`orders_total_id`, `orders_id`, `title`, `text`, `value`, `class`, `sort_order`) VALUES
(17057, 3265, 'Zwischensumme:', '49,04 EUR', '49.0352', 'ot_subtotal', 10),
(17058, 3265, 'Pauschale Versandkosten (Bester Weg):', '4,96 EUR', '4.9600', 'ot_shipping', 25),
(17059, 3265, '<b>Summe, netto</b>:', '<b>54,00 EUR</b>', '53.9952', 'ot_subtotal_no_tax', 40),
(17060, 3265, 'zzgl. MwSt. 19%:', '10,26 EUR', '10.2591', 'ot_tax', 50),
(17061, 3265, '<b>Summe, brutto</b>:', '<b>64,26 EUR</b>', '64.2576', 'ot_total', 99);
```

I would like to separate the shipping cost into netto and gross value. 
The scheme could be

```
SELECT IF(ot_title = 'zzgl. MwSt. 19%:', 
           SUM(ot.value/o.currency_value),  
           SUM((ot.value/1.19)/o.currency_value)
         ) AS shipping
FROM   orders o
JOIN   orders_total ot 
  ON (ot.orders_id = o.orders_id AND ot.class = 'ot_shipping')
WHERE  o.date_purchased >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
AND    o.date_purchased < '2018-01-02 00:00:00'
AND    o.orders_status != 8
```

But the IF condition does not work becauuse I need to access the database row where class='ot_tax'.

Is there a way to realize it with one mysql query?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Updated after OP provided more information, incl. schema

You just need to LEFT JOIN the `orders_total` table with itself to include the required tax field in each row. Then use the field value in your IF condition:

```
SELECT SUM(
         IF(ot2.title = 'inkl. MwSt. 19%:',
            ot.value / 1.19,
            ot.value
         )
       ) as shipping
  FROM orders_total ot
  LEFT JOIN orders_total ot2 
    ON (ot.orders_id = ot2.orders_id AND ot2.class = 'ot_tax')
  WHERE ot.class = 'ot_shipping';
```

Output:

```
shipping
9.91798319
```

To better understand the row structure, have a look at this simpler version of the query without aggregation:

```
SELECT ot.orders_id,  ot.value as shipping, ot2.title as tax 
  FROM orders_total ot
  LEFT JOIN orders_total ot2 
    ON (ot.orders_id = ot2.orders_id AND ot2.class = 'ot_tax')
  WHERE ot.class = 'ot_shipping';
```

Output:

```
orders_id   shipping     tax
3364             5.9     inkl. MwSt. 19%:
3375            4.96     zzgl. MwSt. 19%:
```

Answer (score 0):

Now with more details. This is the datatable schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders_total` (
  `orders_total_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `class` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orders_total_id`),
  KEY `idx_orders_id` (`orders_id`),
  KEY `class` (`class`)
);
```

These are the entries:

```
INSERT INTO `orders_total` (`orders_id`, `title`, `text`, `value`, `class`, `sort_order`) VALUES
(3364, 'Zwischensumme:', '35,38 EUR', '35.3800', 'ot_subtotal', 10),
(3364, 'Pauschale Versandkosten (Bester Weg):', '5,90 EUR', '5.9000', 'ot_shipping', 25),
(3364, 'inkl. MwSt. 19%:', '6,59 EUR', '6.5900', 'ot_tax', 50),
(3364, '<b>Summe</b>:', '<b>41,28 EUR</b>', '41.2800', 'ot_total', 99),
(3375, 'Zwischensumme:', '112,49 EUR', '112.4874', 'ot_subtotal', 10),
(3375, 'Pauschale Versandkosten (Bester Weg):', '4,96 EUR', '4.9600', 'ot_shipping', 25),
(3375, '<b>Summe, netto</b>:', '<b>117,45 EUR</b>', '117.4474', 'ot_subtotal_no_tax', 40),
(3375, 'zzgl. MwSt. 19%:', '22,32 EUR', '22.3150', 'ot_tax', 50),
(3375, '<b>Summe, brutto</b>:', '<b>139,76 EUR</b>', '139.7598', 'ot_total', 99);
```

As you can see the orders_id 3364 is including tax and that's why the shipping cost is 5,90 EUR. The orders_id 3375 is excluding tax and the shipping cost is 4,96 EUR (4,96 + 19% VAT = 5,90 EUR).

With my sql_query the sum of shipping cost should be 9,92 EUR (both times 4,96 EUR).

Comment: I updated my answer according to your new data and schema. The principle doesn't change, though.

Comment: Are you also the author of this database schema?

Comment: No this is a database schema of a shop system. What could be improved?